# Value Help Dialog not working in touchscreen

Tags: sapui5

I am using value help dialog but it does not work with a touchscreen. I cannot select any value. This is my controller.js:

```
    onValueHelpStorageBinDest : function(oEvent) {
    var that = this;
    that.theTokenInput = this.getView().byId("DestinationStorageBinInput");
    this.theTokenInput.setEnableMultiLineMode(sap.ui.Device.system.phone);`     

var oValueHelpDialog = new sap.ui.comp.valuehelpdialog.ValueHelpDialog({
                    // basicSearchText: this.theTokenInput.getValue(),
                    title : "{i18n>SelectStorageBin}",
                    supportMultiselect : true,
                    supportRanges : false,
                    supportRangesOnly : false,
                    // key: this.aKeys[1],
                    // descriptionKey: this.aKeys[1],
                    stretch : sap.ui.Device.system.phone,

                    ok : function(oControlEvent) {
                        // that.aTokens = oControlEvent.getParameter("tokens");
                        // that.theTokenInput.setTokens(that.aTokens);
                        that.getView().byId("DestinationStorageBinInput").setValue();
                        var oCore = sap.ui.getCore();
                        var oDestinationStorageBin = oCore
                                .byId("DestinationStorageBinInput");
                        var oHelpTable = oValueHelpDialog.getTable();
                        var oContext = oHelpTable.getContextByIndex(oHelpTable.getSelectedIndex());

                        if (oContext) {
                            var oSel = oContext.getModel().getProperty(
                                    oContext.getPath());
                            var token2 = new sap.m.Token({
                                key : oSel.Lgpla,
                                text : oSel.Lgpla
                            });
                            var oDestinationStorageBin = oSel.Lgpla;
                            that.aTokens[1] = [ token2 ];
                            that.theTokenInput.setTokens(that.aTokens[1]);
```

When I use normal mouse to select a line, then it works and I can select a line. What can be the reason?
I have checked this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/btJmqQy1Vg21qHRn6HEI?p=preview) and there are the checkboxes in front of the lines, but I do not get them.
Any help is appreciated.
Tim

Comment: Have you tested it with different browsers (IE, Chrome, FireFox, …)?
The plunkr you are referring to gives me different results on IE and Chrome.
What kind of touchscreen do you have: smartphone, tablet,…?
Android, iOS, Windows,… ?

Does this [example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.valuehelpdialog.example1/preview) work with your touchscreen?

Comment: You are right, behaviour depends on the browser. It seems that selection of items does not work with Chrome but works with IE. We are using a windows 8 laptop. I can test the explored example only next week. Does this example you refer to work for you in both Chrome and IE?

Comment: This [example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.valuehelpdialog.example1/preview)
works fine on my Win10 Desktop (no Touchscreen) using the mouse with both Chrome and IE.
It also works ok on a Win10 Surface book using stylus pen.
On my Android 4.4.2 smartphone using Chrome, there is a step in between, where I touch “Select from list”  and then I get the options.
The plunkr you provided works fine here on my Win10 Desktop using Chrome, but with IE I get an empty screen.